# Graphing group of rotation matrices against eachother with a meaningful representation (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, graph, rotation

I have 2 sets of rotation matrices, (3,3,8) for both and I want to plot them in some visually meaningful way. They are both measurements of the same position using different devices so it's comparing the accuracies. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `mesh`, `surf`? Or are you looking for something different?

Comment: Does order matter? You could plot a 2D histogram or heat map if it does not. The two axes would be the two angles of rotation (I'm assuming you're doing 3D rotation) and the colour or bar height would be the count for each angle pair. If order matters just make a normal 2D line plot